# Having trouble connecting to local DynamoDB in Golang

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

**What version of Go are you using (go version)?**

go version go1.18.4 darwin/amd64

**What operating system and processor architecture are you using (go env)?**

```
GO111MODULE="off"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/Users/esthersue/go/bin"
GOCACHE="/Users/esthersue/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/esthersue/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/esthersue/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/esthersue/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.18.4"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOAMD64="v1"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch x86_64 -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/8m/b1hsv_350dnbrshykgb_rjj80000gn/T/go-build2590030861=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

**What did you do?**
This is my first time working with Dyanmodb and Go. I was following this tutorial: https://doncicuto.medium.com/getting-started-with-dynamodb-in-go-part-1-a25c5522edd4
When I run "go run main.go", I get an error. I'm not sure why.

**What did you expect to see?**
I expected to create a table in Dyamnodb.

**What did you see instead?**

```
RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post "http://localhost:8000/": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8000: connect: connection refused
```

Comment: Did you start the server on port 8000?

Comment: @RedBlue I'm pretty sure I did. I followed the tutorial linked above, and got the same thing as they did running: java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb

Comment: Whenever I face a connection issue when using some code, I try to independently confirm that the service is up. I haven't worked with DynamoDB, but it should have some kind of API you can ping/telnet.

Comment: @EstherSue can you please share the output of the command `ps | grep 8000` when you are running your application?
Need to see if dynamo is actually running or not.

Comment: I suggest you run DynamoDb with Docker. This provides two images: one for localstack and another one specific for DynamoDb. It should be easier compared to the approach explained in the tutorial you're following.